# Xpages Computing the combobox number values to save its labales

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a combo box with text for labels and number for values. I want to compute the values of combo box to save text (labels) with creating my own library. I am learning xpages Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox2"
    value="#{document1.status}" style="width:76.0px">
    <xp:this.validators>
        <xp:validateExpression
            message="Please select status.">
            <xp:this.expression><![CDATA[#{javascript:!getComponent("comboBox2").getSubmittedValue().equalsIgnoreCase("-select-")}]]></xp:this.expression>
        </xp:validateExpression>
    </xp:this.validators>
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="-Select-">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Requested" itemValue="10">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="Next Release" itemValue="20">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="Scheduled" itemValue="30">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="Awaiting Additional Info" itemValue="40">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="In Development" itemValue="50">
    </xp:selectItem>


</xp:comboBox>
```

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want to do. Do you want to compute the select items for your combobox? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Lausten, I am learning English and there is nobody to check my comment sorry if I confused you.Values of combo box are number, when a user select a value from combo box the number will save this is that I don't want .I want to create a function to save text that are in labels not the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sven Hasselbach wrote a function to get the selected label value. I tested it with your posted code and it works:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/xpagesforum.nsf/xpTopicThread.xsp?documentId=20F1270812F4BD55852579890054C09F

```
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox2" style="width:76.0px">
    <xp:this.validators>
        <xp:validateExpression message="Please select status.">
            <xp:this.expression><![CDATA[#{javascript:!getComponent("comboBox2").getSubmittedValue().equalsIgnoreCase("-select-")}]]></xp:this.expression>
        </xp:validateExpression>
    </xp:this.validators>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="-Select-">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Requested" itemValue="10">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Next Release" itemValue="20">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Scheduled" itemValue="30">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Awaiting Additional Info" itemValue="40">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="In Development" itemValue="50">
    </xp:selectItem>



    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="comboBox2">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:function getSelectedLabel( id ) {
   var ComboBox = getComponent( id );
   var value = ComboBox.value;

   var ChildrenList:java.util.ListIterator;
   ChildrenList = ComboBox.getChildren().listIterator();
   while (ChildrenList.hasNext()) {
      var Child = ChildrenList.next();

      /*** process computed / multiple values ***/
      if( typeof( Child ) == 'com.ibm.xsp.component.UISelectItemsEx' ){
         var hlp = Child.getValue();
         for( var i=0; i< hlp.length; i++ ){
             if( hlp[i].getValue() == value )
             return hlp[i].getLabel() ;
         }
      }

      /*** process single values ***/
      if( typeof( Child ) == 'com.ibm.xsp.component.UISelectItemEx' ){

      if( Child.getItemValue() == value )
          return Child.getItemLabel();
      }
   }
}

var value = getSelectedLabel("comboBox2")

view.postScript("console.log('" + value + "')")}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:comboBox>
```

You can see in the browser console that if you click the label, the correct value of the label is logged.

Now you have got access to the labels in the "value" variable.

Comment: Thanks poisonedYouth, I am really beginner in xpages and never use function in xpages and I don't know how call a function in xpages Could you please post the code that you tested or write down the steps you did.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help poisonedYouth I used the above code but again it displays number instead of label in the view panel I want to display label in the view not number.